# Magento 2 - Visual Merchandiser rebuild automatically

Tags: magento2, product, category, indexing

I'm using Magento Visual Merchandiser to create smart categories. I created conditions to add products into my smart categories, but if I update product attributes value, the products didn't add automatically into my smart categories. I should go in the specific smart category and save it. It's possibile to "rebuild" these categories automatically? I thought that with indexes this behavior was as default :(

I also tried to create a dependency between `catalog_category_product` (Category Products) and `catalog_product_attribute` (Product EAV), but not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Indexer/etc/indexer.xsd">
    <indexer id="catalog_category_product">
        <dependencies>
            <indexer id="catalog_product_attribute"/>
        </dependencies>
    </indexer>
    <indexer id="amasty_xsearch_category_fulltext">
        <dependencies>
            <indexer id="catalog_product_attribute"/>
        </dependencies>
    </indexer>
</config>
```

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: I'm also looking for same solution.

Comment: This is not working because you actually need a record in `catalog_category_product` to update the `catalog_category_product` index (`catalog_category_product_index_store1` etc). Triggering an update of the index can be done by triggering a save of the specific categories (which can get quite heavy).